# How to invert a pulser and connect a door to it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Obviously inverting a pulsar is kind of redundant, since it goes on and off repeatedly...
however, when I want it to stop, a lever would do just fine, but it would keep it powered on.
but what if I wanted the object its connected to be by default off?
I can't use an inverter because the second I'll turn on the pulsar the inverter would fry and stop working, cutting the circuit.
so how do I make an inverter that can withstand a pulsar?

Comment: Um, I've inverted the input of pulsers just fine in the past... can we get schematics/screenshot of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you just want the clock to cycle when the lever is in the `ON` position, and stop cycling when the lever is in the `OFF` position? Like badp said, you should be able to just invert the lever signal just fine - a schematic would be great.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8vYJG.gif
Top Circuit shows the original state, a pulsar (i want the fastest stable one- a 4 torch one) connected to a door.
Middle Circuit shows a pulsar stopped by a lever, door default is ON, which is bad for me.
Bottom Circuit shows possible solution, however, because the torches take turns shorting and cooling down (in minecraft, not the sim), the door would pulsate only 1/4 of the time.
@Kevin @badp

Comment: Ahh, I see. Pulsars aren't technically stable as they rely on torches burning out and starting up again, so I don't know how you would accomplish this. Do you really need a pulsar or could you get away with a 4-clock?

Answer (score 4):

So, first off, here's what a basic pulser with an enabling switch looks like.

[image: A rapid pulser with inverted input.]

[image: A rapid pulser with inverted input flipped on.]

The problem with connecting a door – or anything – to this contraption via Redstone is that the relative torch will no longer be part of the pulser. I'm not going to think about why is that – this is a weird contraption anyway – so here's the workaround:

**The door needs to replace one of the non-vital torches.**

The vital torches are those connected by the middle Redstone cross. Everything else is non vital (= removing it won't break the pulser) and can be replaced by a door *in place.*

Another important thing to remember is that **the switch must not be right next to the door,** or the current will simply flow from the switch to the door directly, ignoring the pulser entirely.

[image: An extended rapid pulser with doors.]

In this unpolished proof of concept, I brought the switch forward and replaced one of the side torches with a door. Since the door is directly wired to the pulser, it pulses with it.

It is incidentally a little known fact that you can extend pulsers at will by adding more blocks with Redstone on them and non-vital torches on the sides.

Comment: but if you will connect a door to the pulsar it will still not function normally.
the point is:
when the pulsar is working, door is pulsating constantly without break.
when pulsar is not working, the door is in her closed state.

Comment: @Wussup addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple sticky piston clock myself, since a pulser isn't technically stable to begin with. The piston can never burn out, and I can set it to "off" by just powering the piston.

Here's a top-down view:

```
l=lever
p=sticky piston
r=redstone repeater
b=solid block
-=Wire

- - - -
- r p b 
    l
```

With a redstone torch underneath the solid block, and the repeater set to the desired delay (a 1-tick piston clock is still pretty fast).

This way, it never burns out, and the lever deactivates it.

Comment: In case you didn't get a notification for it: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14846/the-great-minecraft-tag-family-cleanup#comment44968_14846 And please flag this comment here as "no longer needed" once you've noticed it, it's really off-topic here, but I saw no other way to contact you.